# convert mongodb _id to string perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

Trying to get the guid / string representation of the mongodb _id field.

I'm using the MongoDB Perl module and when I print the `$cursor->{'_id'}`, it looks like a bunch of special chars (`╪«añσ%CñQ`).

Dumper says it is actually a hash:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'data' => '╪«añσ%CñQ
ô╢_ú',
                 'subtype' => 3
               }, 'MongoDB::BSON::Binary' );
```

The problem is, the data field does not appear to be something I can convert to a string and I have been unable to find any info on how to do this using Perl. Mongo version is: 3.2.5.

In the end, all I really want is to be able to do the mongo equivalent of `select column from table where _id = (select id from other table where name = bla)`.

Comment: Note: I tried using MongoDB::OID which has a to_string method but when I try 'my $oid = MongoDB::OID->new("value" => $row->{'_id'});' I get 'is not a valid OID (in $args->{"value"})'.

Comment: Re "*In the end, all I really want is to be able to do the mongo equivalent of "select column from table where _id = (select id from other table where name = bla)"*", What have you tried?

Comment: In the Mongo Robo 3t UI, this query works: db.getCollection('TestSuiteMetrics').find({"TestRunId":LUUID("83b0c82e-676b-6841-b358-d50af1cbb1d3")}) In perl, I saved the _id hash thing I got in the original query and used it in this find using perl: $collection->find({"TestRunId" => $testRunId}); This does not work but the UI shows that the LUUID guid value is the same in both cases. I think the problem is in the 'data' value of the hash returned using the MongoDB perl module.

Comment: MongoDB document `_id` can be any type.  In this case, it looks like binary data.  That's odd but not impossible.  More odd is that your example is `$cursor->{'_id'}`.  Could you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: The 'data' value from the _id hash object ended up being the value from the Mongo _id field as a .NET guid. By changing the 'Legacy UUID Encoding' in Robo 3T to 'Use .NET Encoding' and then using the Data::UUID.to_string() method on the _id hash object, I was able to see that the values matched between perl and Robo 3T and using the _id object as is in the find method worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' value from the _id hash object ended up being the value from the Mongo _id field as a .NET guid. By changing the 'Legacy UUID Encoding' in Robo 3T to 'Use .NET Encoding' and then using the Data::UUID.to_string() method on the _id hash object, I was able to see that the values matched between perl and Robo 3T and using the _id object as is in the find method worked as expected.